# LOCAL_ONE and QUORUM produce different results

Tags: cassandra, quorum

I'm connecting to Cassandra DB via IntelliJ Data Source and run an ad-hoc query.  We have this DB in multiple data centers. My connection string includes just a single node IP.

With the same query and the same URL (connection string) I got different results (more returned rows) when I switched from `LOCAL_ONE` (apparently the default) to `QUORUM`.

Apparently we have a replication problem.

Based on the info I presented so far, is it possible to determine whether the discrepancy is between nodes is the same data center or between data centers?

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of unknowns here: version of C*, whether repairs are configured properly and are running, replication factor configured at the table schema, etc.,

In general, one should *always* leverage `LOCAL_QUORUM` consistency levels (`CL`) for both reads and writes queries as that will be the most efficient for most of the use cases connecting your application to the closest datacenter/region for faster & accurate responses.

Read more [here](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/architecture/dynamo.html#tunable-consistency) to understand various [tunable] consistency levels and how you could leverage them.

In general using `LOCAL_ONE` read CL is going to be your fastest, but may not be pulling the most up to date data because it will just wait for 1 replica to respond prior to acknowledging the read request. Whereas, if you use a `QUORUM` read CL, in your case since you've more than 1 datacenter/region, it *can* span across the datacenters/regions to wait for a majority of replicas to respond to your client (IntelliJ here) request. It doesn't matter if you only have 1 local datacenter/region IP address as that would just be used as the contact point and the driver will immediately figure out the entire topology of the cluster and can use any. If you want to ensure you read the most up to date data, and also have an optimal response times, you would use `LOCAL_QUORUM` read CL in this case. I hope that helps. [Bonus] I would request you to spend some time leveraging [this free browser-only-based tutorial](https://www.datastax.com/learn/cassandra-fundamentals) to understand Cassandra® fundamentals for more clarity.